# SQL query result in a string (or variable)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, variables, string

Is it possible to output SQL query result in one string or variable? (i'm bad in php and mysql)
Let's say I have db "agents" with columns - agent_id, agent_fname, agent_lname, agent_dept.

Using this query:

```
$sql = SELECT a.`agent_fname` FROM agents a WHERE a.`agent_dept` = 'FCA'
```

I want to get a string or a variable, so I can use it in any place of my php file (i.e. $my_variable which outputs the result of my query). Is it possible? If yes - how?

Thank you!

*I have more than one row.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are doing something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query ($link, $sql).
```

The 'i' in mysqli is for 'improved' which is what you should be using these days.

This $result is not your output yet.  You must call:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     print_r ($row);
}
```

The above code gives you $row, which is your actual output, in the form of an array.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("Name: %s", $row['agent_fname'],);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass around a single variable representing your records.  You *could* build a two dimensional array.  like:

```
$records = array();
$mysqli_result = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $records[] = $row;
}
```

This will give you an array variable, $records, will all of your results.  Which is easy to pass around. (maybe as an arg to another function.)  **HOWEVER**, this is a pattern that can eat up a lot of memory.

It is much better to pass around the $mysqli_result.