# Combine Entry Count in a UNION Query

Tags: php, mysql, count, union

How do i combine the counts from all the tables being used in  a UNION query.  This is what i have:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num
from table_one LEFT JOIN table_constant on table_one.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id 
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as num
from table_two LEFT JOIN table_constant on table_two.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id 
where table_two.added_by = '$uid'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as num
from table_three LEFT JOIN table_constant ON table_three.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as num
from table_four LEFT JOIN table_constant ON table_four.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
ORDER BY date_time_added DESC";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put count outside and apply it on sub query containing all tables union result.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ...) as abc
```

Or try this out

```
Select mytable .userid, sum(mytable .subcount) as totalcount from
(
select userid, count(*) as subcount from table1 group by userid
union all
select userid, count(*) as subcount from table2 group by userid
)
as mytable 
group by mytable .userid
```

or try using FULL OUTER JOIN instead of union it will give you the same result..

```
 SELECT Count(UserID), UserId
 FROM MyTable1
 GROUP BY MyTable1.UserID
 UNION
 SELECT Count(UserID), UserId
 FROM MyTable2
 FULL OUTER JOIN MyTable2 ON (MyTable1.UserId=MyTable2.UserId)
 GROUP BY MyTable2.UserID
```

**Updated answer:**

IF Your query is working fine follow my first option that i gave means

```
 select count(*) from (your query) as pagecount..
```

Then your query would be like this.....

```
  select count(*) from
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as num
   from table_one LEFT JOIN table_constant on table_one.c_id 
  = table_constant.c_id 
  where table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
 UNION
 SELECT COUNT(*) as num
from table_two LEFT JOIN table_constant on table_two.c_id 
 = table_constant.c_id 
 where table_two.added_by = '$uid'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as num
from table_three LEFT JOIN table_constant ON table_three.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as num
from table_four LEFT JOIN table_constant ON table_four.c_id 
= table_constant.c_id
where table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
ORDER BY date_time_added DESC") as pagecount
```

Comment: Hey.  i need the count inside a variabel which is $total_pages as posted above.  i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I have updated my answer check this out.If you are fulfilling union rules in your query then do this. select count(*) from (your query) as mycount. It worked for me hope now you will get rid of your problem..

Comment: one more thing Syeda.  How do i put it into a variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228382/sql-query-result-in-a-string-or-variable

Comment: This link will help you to get the result in variable

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the whole thing in yet another query and do the summation there.

```
SELECT sum(num)
FROM ( ... union queries here ...) as subquery;
```

Or loop over the returned rows in PHP and do the summation yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way to write that :/.  A union is very powerful, but you are calling 4 selects in a single query, and if that is run every page, it will really hurt performance.

To answer you question, something like:

```
SELECT
    SUM (mnTbl.num) as sumNum
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as num
        FROM
                table_one
            LEFT JOIN
                table_constant
            ON
                table_one.c_id = table_constant.c_id 
        WHERE
            table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
    UNION
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as num
        FROM
                table_two
            LEFT JOIN
                table_constant
            ON
                table_two.c_id = table_constant.c_id 
        WHERE
            table_two.added_by = '$uid'
    UNION
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as num
        FROM
                table_three
            LEFT JOIN
                table_constant
            ON
                table_three.c_id = table_constant.c_id
        WHERE
            table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
    UNION
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) as num
        FROM
                table_four
            LEFT JOIN
                table_constant
            ON
                table_four.c_id  = table_constant.c_id
        WHERE
            table_constant.user_id = '$uid'
    ) as mnTbl
ORDER BY
    date_time_added DESC
```

Comment: Hope it works, can't really test sql statements with out some sample data

Comment: what do i put for mnTbl.num? table name?

Comment: What do you mean it rendered the same way, I can't see how it would give the same results as the previous query.

Comment: i plugged in what you pasted.  despite that the pagination won't show.

Comment: Did you try just running my query? In say phpmyAdmin.  It could be a problem with your php.  I did change the name from `num` to `sumNum`.  Could that have caused it?

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin.  i am not sure what do to with this one.  If you look at my query its for a pagination script.  the count value has to go into the $total_pages so that the script can further split the pages.  Here is the compelte script, this might help i thought it was irrelevant since the count query was important:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482025/complicated-query-pagination-script